# Lookup field displays properly in Lightning App preview but not when component is added to page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, forceinputfield

I followed [these steps](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143211/forceinputfield-for-lookup-giving-an-error) to create a lookup field that works well in the Lightning App Preview. However, if I try to add this component to a page, the lookup field is no longer rendered at all.

```
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" 
               default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }" access = "public"/>

<force:inputField aura:id="accountid" 
                 value="{!v.contact.AccountId}"/>
```

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: please share your code - we can then easily see where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using this method instead. More work is involved but we get more control over the component in the end.

https://meltedwires.com/2015/10/27/salesforce-lightning-lookup-component/

Comment: Lightningstrike.io has some good components as well

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [this](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/07/custom-lookup-lightning-component/) as an example to create a lookup. I implemented this a few weeks ago and works really good.