# Force:input field not working for Lookup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I am using Force:inputfield to display a lookup field to account on my custom lightning component. We have two components one for the creation and the other for editing. In the edit component, the field is not even displaying. Any idea of how to bind the value to this lookup field?

Comment: Can you show code

Comment: check this thread [force:input for custom lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143211/forceinputfield-for-lookup-giving-an-error).